# heroku shows file not found / 500 for files that exist in file system

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have a flask + react app that works fine locally. When I deploy to heroku, I get a 500 error when trying to load a `metrics.yaml` file from Flask:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../build', static_url_path='/')

@app.route('/')
def index():
  metrics = load_metrics(url_for('static', filename='metrics.yaml'))
```

This results in a 500 server error and the whole site does not load. `heroku logs --tail` reveals:

```
No such file or directory: '/metrics.yaml'

2021-07-15T16:44:56.490218+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/metrics.yaml" host=react-flask-heroku-bp.herokuapp.com request_id=6c5561ad-e8b4-49da-bba0-5342052a19a0 fwd="73.25.235.134" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=45ms status=200 bytes=1320 protocol=https
2021-07-15T16:49:45.626217+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=react-flask-heroku-bp.herokuapp.com request_id=48f85a02-744c-4c1e-a52f-f063ee1213e8 fwd="73.25.235.134" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
```

But if I point my browser to the `https://[site].herokuapp.com/metrics.yaml` file, I can see it just fine.

One thing that confuses me there is that the `method=GET path="/metrics.yaml"` seems to show a `200` status, followed by the `method=GET path="/"` showing a 500 error. Why is that?

How do I resolve this so that I can load the `/metrics.yaml` file from the web root without a 500 error?

---UPDATE---

I've noticed that no matter what address I put in here, even an absolute path: `https:/mhtransfers.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics.yaml`

results in a

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https:/mhtransfers.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics.yaml'
```

---

Here's the build folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Can your share a link to the repository? Difficult to answer without the setup.

Comment: also can you share the folder structure

Comment: @MoritzMakowski - repo is here: https://github.com/heaversm/react-flask-heroku-bp

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan - the folder structure can be seen in the repo - i'll modify the question to include a screenshot of the build folder

Comment: @mheavers Maybe you can try printing out `url_for('static', filename='.')` in order to see where this is pointing at.

I used to deploy to heroku and organize flask+react like that. However, by now I have switched to using two separate codebases and two distinct servers. On heroku this might be more expensive since you can only buy "dynos". But by now I am hosting all of my stuff on Google Cloud Run, AWS Fargate (Both fully managed containers) or Netlify (for Gatsby sites).

I can highly recommend you to look into those options since I think this setup is way cleaner - and cheaper as well.

Comment: One more thing: With `heroku local` you can run the app locally just like you described in the Procfile. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this via the following:

```
from pathlib import Path
metrics_file = Path(__file__).parent / "metrics.yaml"
metrics = load_metrics(metrics_file)
```

This allowed me to target the proper path without an environment specific variable and using relative pathing on both server and local.